# Use of $\arg\max$

Tags: optimization

I need help with writing out a function with arg max. 
I have a vector $\mathbf{h}$, I would like to select the index that corresponds to the m-dominant values in  $\mathbf{h}$. 
Thanks in anticipation for you any response that can help.

Comment: The context isn't clear, which function is it?

Answer (score 0):

For vectors ${\bf h}\in{\mathbb R}^n$ define ${\bf h}^>$ to be the vector obtained by rearranging the entries of ${\bf h}$ in decreasing $(\geq)$  order. Then the $m^{\rm th}$ largest entry of ${\bf h}$ is $h^>_m$.